# Cannot increase MTU on gigabit network

Tags: linux, networking, jumboframes

I have just set up my new gigabit network and when I was about to increase the MTU to use jumbo frames, I get this error:

> root@rayquang-desktop:~# ifconfig eth1 mtu 9000
>   SIOCSIFMTU: Invalid argument

Could anyone help me to increase the MTU.

Details: NIC: NETGEAR GA311; Switch: NETGEAR GS105, running Ubuntu 10.10 and Debian Lenny on desktop, server respectively.

Help would be greatly appreciated,
RayQuang

Comment: It seems that your NIC does not support jumbo frames!

Comment: khaled is right. try lower values, ~7000 works on my NICs

Comment: aparantly 1500 is the maximum that i can get :(. Is there no other choice but buying a better NIC? If i should buy a new one which one should it be? Thanks, RayQuang

Comment: Remember that the switches also must have the ports configured to use jumbo frames or BTWH

Comment: @coredump I checked the PDF datasheet for the switch, apparently that model does support JF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep.  I just looked at the [PDF datasheet](http://www.netgear.co.uk/pdfs/ga311.pdf) for your NIC

No mention of Jumbo Frame support there, so I suspect you're out of luck.

Buy a new nic.  Go for [something Intel](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/prodbrief/319831.pdf) or Broadcom and you'll probably have more luck.  Shouldn't set you back [too much](http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?q=intel+gigabit+ct+desktop&hl=en&cid=11796284025423384463&ei=Gy8bTYaxLJOswQWZwfytDA&sa=title&ved=0CAkQ8wIwADgA#p).

Comment: Or just forget about jumbo frames; it's not like they make much difference with current CPU's @1Gb.

Comment: ~20% throughput improvement is not to be sniffed at, don't know if its worth spending cash though.

Comment: @Sirex: 20% under what circumstances? @work I just measured 940 Mb/s using iperf without jumbo frames, which is 94% of the theoretical maximum, so a 20% improvement is just impossible in that case. (CPU usage was 5% of one core on the sender and 1% on the receiver; not only CPU's but also NIC's and the network stack in OS'es are different from 10 years ago.)

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need jumbo frames in the first place?

It is not common on desktop PCs.

UPDATE:
@Sirex I still think it is uncommon in home environment. He has netgear nic and switch. These are a SOHO stuff. People should not use some technology because it has a good name. They do because of real need.

I run high-end blade servers and I do not feel the need for jumbo frames.

UPDATE2:
@RayQuang Then I think upgrading your switch and NIC can help much more than enabling jumbo frames. Others already suggested Broadcom and Intel as a NIC and I suggest Cisco (not the small business thingy) or HP as a switch.

Comment: this sums it up overall, and imho it's not that uncommon on gigabit networks; http://63.196.71.246/~phil/jumbo.html

Comment: @Sirex I still think it is uncommon in home environment. He has netgear nic and switch. These are a SOHO stuff. // I edited my answer to include this. //

Comment: Swings and roundabouts i guess. I only know of 3 home networks running at gigabit speeds. All use jumbo frames. (n.b: I didn't set those networks up, but mine also uses jumbo @ gigabit)

Comment: I'm sorry if I did not make it clear that this is is for a corporate network that just in this case happens to be in a home. I need the high throughput for large data transfers of OS images and for the link with database and other application servers.